# Как сделать чтобы из БД выводились все значения?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Как сделать чтобы из БД выводились все значения? БД у меня redbeanphp. Пример кода при котором выводится только 1 значение:

```
<?php

$user=R::load('ludi', 1);

?>
```

Comment: redbeanphp не БД, во-первых, покажите структуру базы данных, во-вторых, подключение к базе данных, в третьих покажите / напишите ваш сервер на котором всё это дело у вас работает. Слишком мало информации, поэтому вариаций проблемы может быть много. Больше информации вы предоставите, более точный ответ вы получите.

Answer (score 1):

https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/queries

Почему бы не воспользоваться их документацией?

```
R::getAll( 'select * from ludi' );
```

или

https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/loading_a_bean

```
R::batch('ludi',array(1,2,3)); // и т.д
```

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать